# Calculate Current Date and Time or Time Duration Independent of Client Windows OS Date and Time

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I want a way to get the current date and time independent of client device or to calculate time duration (for example 5 hours or 6 days) between two points.

**Why?**

Because I don’t want to allow users of my application to change their OS date and time and bypass my licensing strategy.

Let me tell you an example: 
I have some information on client machine

1. LastOnlineLoginDate : DateTime
2. ExpirationDate : DateTime
3. MaxDaysClientCanLoginOffline : int

So when a client login to my app and he is offline I have two ways to check his license:

1. If ExpirationDate > **DateTime.Now** so he is licensed and can continue
2. If LastOnlineLogin+(**Time Duration Between LastOnlineLogin and Now**) < MaxDaysClientCanLoginOffline so he is licensed and can continue

I’ll be appreciated if you help me to get    **DateTime.Now**  or **calculate Time Duration Between LastOnlineLogin and Now**

Comment: Is your application allowed to access internet?

Comment: Can you provide us with whatever code you already have written? It'd be useful

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - My thoughts exactly...get the time from a third party server.

Comment: The only way I know of is what Windows itself does for "trial" validation. It's very complicated. If you can't validate against a server somewhere, you might as well consider yourself out of luck. In fact, even if you can, it's usually rather easy to create a crack that just bypasses the check :)

Comment: you could also store the last datetime that the application was used and check to see if the app is opened "before" the last datetime (therefore catching them reseting the clock) and prevent loading, but if the user is going to such lengths to use your app illegally, they will probably just crack it like Luaan states and this is just going to annoy the users who have paid for the service.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you should notice that the problem is when there's no internet and so no third party server,if the user login to my app while he's online i do licensing terms successfully

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa i'm in design time and so there's no code,and you should know that there are no complicated codes but complicated design and approach

Comment: @Luaan is the Windows validation approach public?(of cource NOT :D),Do you know any information or additional link about this approach?

Comment: @KevinCook your suggestion "Rang a bell in my mind"

Comment: Is there any way to calculate the lifetime of OS or some hardwares like  CPU?
I think if I can calculate that, I can evaluate that the current date and time of OS is real or fake?
Am i right?

Comment: You'll find information about it all over the internet, but it's all reverse engineered, so I'm not going to help you find it :) In any case, the final point still is - it got cracked and it didn't take long. DRM simply doesn't work, and the simpler your software, the easier it is to bypass. Given how fast it was bypassed in something as complex as a full blown OS, and given that decompiled C# code is easy to understand and modify, your only chance is to never attract any crackers with .NET skills at all. It's an uphill battle, and in the end you're just hurting your paying customers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there’s no way to do what I want.

So here is some approach to check the Date and Time:

1. I keep last login date and some other informations in windows registry(This approach is so dependent on the encryption of the data that I keep in client windows registry).
2. Create and run a windows service on client OS at installation time to listen for windows date and time changed event (this is a disadvantage for my app because for installation of my app the user logged in have to be Administrator).
3. When the user wants to login the current date and time must be greater than last login date(@kevinCook).
4. If the user logged in offline, while app is running in a background thread, check the internet connection for validating the user.

Thank you so much.

Sincerely.